# find all jpg and png at the same time

Tags: bash, shell

So I want to resize all jpg and png in 1 script

here is what is currently using, is there any way to run this for jpg and png at the same time?

```
  find file/path -type f -name '*.PNG' -exec sips -Z 800 -s formatOptions  60 {} \;
```

Comment: I have never used `sips` but can't you just use `sips -Z 800 *.jpg *.png` ?

Comment: @PesaThe: Good point, but not recursive as `find` is.

Comment: @DevSolar From the original question I figured OP wanted to resize only images in the current directory. `find` is indeed the right solution when searching recursively or you may utilize `**/*.jpg` and `**/*.png` as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"How to make `find` find files based on two different patterns": the `-o` ("or") option.

```
find file/path -type f \( -name '*.PNG' -o -name '*.JPG' \) -exec ...
```

Note that your question should have been phrased like that, as it has nothing to do with `sips` in particular.

Note that you can use `-iname` for case-insensitive matching, in case not all your file extensions are uppercase.

Comment: Thank you so much and the -iname  notes is a life saver.

Comment: @user15849: I strongly suggest going [`man find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and reading all of it. This tool is a real powerhouse, and you should be fully aware of the many things it could do for you.

Comment: -iname is case insensitive

Comment: @phillipsK: Yes. That is what I wrote. ;-)

Comment: Note that multiple options have to be included in `\( ... \))` to be properly evaluated, else if present a JPG it will be not found any PNG (see the bottom of `man find` for the explanation). So it should be something like  `find file/path -type f \( -iname '*.PNG' -o -iname '*.JPG' \) -exec ...whatever \;`